# Método $_GET[] PHP

Tags: php, array, get

Estou utilizando o método $_GET[] no php e ele está retornando o seguinte error:
"Não acessar o Array SuperGlobal direto $_GET diretamente."

segue o código:

```
<?php 
  function COMP($Comp, $Lar, $Alt){
    echo $Vol =$Comp*$Lar*$Alt;                            
}
  $Comp = isset($_GET['COMP'])?$_GET['COMP']:0;
  $Lar = isset($_GET['LAR'])?$_GET['LAR']:0;
  $Alt = isset($_GET['ALT'])?$_GET['ALT']:0;

  COMP($Comp, $Lar, $Alt);                        
?>
```

Obrigado pelo ajuda.

Comment: Ele quem? o netbeans?

Comment: sim o NetBeans!

Comment: Nessa código ai não vejo tem problema.